# How to model a multiplicative effect of a parameter

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, hierarchical-bayesian

I am having difficulty in fitting a model on data. Basically, I have data about the evaluation of phenotypic property (i.e. hard) of 65 palm trees by 5 judges. As an evaluation scheme, each judge provides score to each sample. For 3 judges sample data look like this:

```
Judge       Product                  Hard

aa             1                      5

ab             1                      6

ac             1                      3

aa             1                      7 

ab             1                      5

ac             1                      4

aa             2                      5

ab             2                      8

ac             2                      6

aa             2                      7

ab             2                      4

ac             2                      4
```

Main objective here is to get product coefficients with less judge errors, for which I want to fit this kind of model:

$$Y_{ij} = α_i + β_iθ_j + ε_{ij}$$
*i* = judge, *j* = product

Here, $α_i$ is judge main coefficients, $_i$ is judge coefficients due to difference in their scoring pattern and $θ_j$ is product coefficients and $ε_i$ is assessor dependent.

I was trying to fit this model using `lme` function in R, but difficulty I am facing to fit the interaction term because model here fitted for parameters rather than co-variates.

This model looks quite accurate for my kind of data. I have seen Bayesian version (http://www.r-bloggers.com/extending-the-sensory-profiling-data-model/) of it and I don't know how to do using mixed-modelling approach or in a frequentist way.

My queries here are:

a) What can be an appropriate method to fit this kind of model? I had referred so much literature where description about iterative generalized least squares, multi-level model, separate regression model, weighted least-square model are given. But still I am not getting how to use and fit estimated value of parameters in interaction terms and get separate coefficients for both interaction parameters?

b) How can I get heterogeneous error in this form?

c) which R package can I use?

Comment: By 'hard' do you mean 'hardness'? Hardness sounds like a property.

Comment: Yes, its just an example, I have several other phenotypic attributes also but data format is same. I am using using single response variable at a time.